# MS Word: Derive Styles from Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles

I have copied text from a web page to MS Word (2010). The formatting of this document is done via CSS, and all headers and text is formatted in a consistent way.

The formatting is retained by Word after copy pasting.

However, the complete text has the style "Normal" applied to it. I would like to create and apply Word styles to correspond with the headers, lists, images and text. I know that I can create a new style based on a selection (which I've done), but Word then only recognizes that paragraph to have this new style; all the other paragraphs still have the Normal style applied, although the formatting of the text is the same.

Since I would rather not manually go through this rather large document to select pieces of text and apply a style myself, my question boils down to this: is there a way to say "Give all these equally formatted pieces of text the same style," or "Create styles based on the different formatting of paragraphs you find in this document?" If not, are there any tips which would make this task easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Select Text With Similar Formatting](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-select-text-with-similar-formatting-in-word-2007/) option before generating the new styles?

Comment: Great tip! This is something I overlooked in Word 2007/2010. The option does not recognize all paragraphs containing the same formatting (maybe due to some less visible formatting options), but it significantly decreased to amount of time I've to spent setting all the styles by scrolling through the complete doc.